# A Tikz matrix with 'inside' border lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

How should I write my latex code so that the `tikz` two-column matrix has one inside vertical line (the border between left and right columns) and one horizontal line (the border between 1st and 2nd rows)?  See the attached screenshot below.

Right now, my code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[
        matrix of nodes,
        every node/.style={
            draw, 
            minimum width=2in, minimum height=.3in,
            },
        column 1/.style={text width=2in,align=left},
        column 2/.style={text width=2in,align=left},
        row 1/.style={align=center},
        row 2/.style={align=left},
    ]
    {
    \textbf{Assets} & \textbf{Liabilities \& Net Worth} \\
    Financial Assets ($FA$) & Financial Liabilities ($FL$) \\
    \hspace{.3in}$FA$, domestic MoU & \hspace{.3in}$FL$, domestic MoU \\
    \hspace{.3in}$FA$, foreign MoU & \hspace{.3in}$FL$, foreign MoU \\
    Non-Financial Assets ($NFA$) & Net Worth ($NW$) \\
    Total Assets ($FA+NFA$) & Total Liabilities ($FL+NW$) \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Typical balance sheet}
    \label{fig:tbs}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should use a table. See the `tabularray` package that is easy-to-use and powerful

Comment: And package booktabs.

Comment: @MS-SPO `booktabs` doesn't go well with vertical lines, better an ordinary `tabular`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With table is much simpler, especially if you use `tabularray` package as @projetmbc suggested in his comment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {l l},
             row{1}  = {c, font=\bfseries},
             hline{2} = 0.8pt, vline{2} = 0.8pt
             }
Assets                      &   Liabilities \& Net Wort         \\
Financial Assets ($FA$)     &   Financial Liabilities ($FL$)    \\
\quad   $FA$, domestic MoU  &   \quad   $FL$, domestic MoU      \\
\quad   $FA$, foreign MoU   &   \quad   $FL$, foreign MoU       \\
Non-Financial Assets ($NFA$)&   Net Worth ($NW$)                \\
Total Assets ($FA+NFA$)     & Total Liabilities ($FL+NW$) 
\end{tblr}
    \caption{Typical balance sheet}
    \label{fig:tbs}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
If for some reason you prefer to draw your table and at this use `matrix` Ti*k*Z library,
than try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes = {text width=1.8in, minimum height=.2in, align=left},
             column sep=1em,
             row 1/.style={align=center, font=\bfseries},
            ]
{
Assets                      &   Liabilities \& Net Wort         \\
Financial Assets ($FA$)     &   Financial Liabilities ($FL$)    \\
\quad   $FA$, domestic MoU  &   \quad   $FL$, domestic MoU      \\
\quad   $FA$, foreign MoU   &   \quad   $FL$, foreign MoU       \\
Non-Financial Assets ($NFA$)&   Net Worth ($NW$)                \\
Total Assets ($FA+NFA$)     & Total Liabilities ($FL+NW$)       \\
    };
\draw[semithick]    (m-1-2.south -| m.west) -- (m-1-2.south -| m.east)
                    (m.north) -- (m.south);              
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Typical balance sheet}
\label{fig:tbs}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Resulted figure is similar to one before:

[image]

Comment: @projetmbc, sorry for for noted a wrong comment author. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Don't worry, I just fired my lawyer. :-)

Comment: @Zarko -- thank you for such a simple solution!